# Apache Drill-embedded can't connect due to VPN

Tags: apache, vpn, apache-drill

I'm trying to use Apache Drill in embedded mode (drill-embedded) however when it starts it shows an error:

> Error: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.pc.RpcException: CONNECTION : io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.1.11:31010 (state=,code=0)

If I disconnect the corporate VPN it will startup just fine. Connections to the IP of the network adapter are being blocked by the VPN software, which is expected, so I need it to connect to the loopback (127.0.0.1) instead. How can I configure this? I have several other server/services running fine that use the loopback, but for whatever reason Drill insists on using the IP of the adapter.

I've tried various settings in `drill-override.conf` but can't seem to find the right one that would cause it to connect to the loopback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the mailing list, Aditya says:

> Could you please check your "/etc/hosts" file for a possible
> mis-configuration of "localhost" and ensure that all localhost names
> are set to default.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to work around it by setting the environment variable `DRILL_HOST_NAME=localhost`. I think you can also set this in `conf/drill-env.sh`, there's a line there that exports that environment variable and you can uncomment it and set a value.